# Odd behaviour when importing classes

Tags: java, import, drjava

I am currently using [DrJava](http://www.drjava.org/) and when I write the following `import` statement:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

I get the following error message:

> Error: The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved

What am I doing wrong? The other `import` statements work perfectly fine.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* Frankly; using Dr Java.

Comment: Try to compile the program with javac and see if it reports an error. If not DrJava needs an examination! The java.util.Arrays class has been part of the JDK since 1.2, so as far as I can determine the import is correct.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch My professor teaches with DrJava so I didn't really had a choice

Comment: @Maya Did you install the `JRE` correctly? Double check that. And check project properties

Comment: @ewramner I get this error message when I compile my code. The message pops up even if only the import statement is present.

Comment: @HasithaMJayawardana How do I check that?

Comment: @Maya Check your program files folder. Where did you install the JDK?

Comment: @HasithaMJayawardana I downloaded it and created a shortcut on my desktop

Comment: Have you got `class Arrays` in the same file?

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, that's why I need the import Array statement

Comment: @Maya I think you misunderstand: I am not asking if you are invoking a method from `java.util.Arrays`, I am asking if you have *declared* your own class called `Arrays`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Do you mean if I called my class Arrays? If so, no I didn't.

Comment: I meant compile the code from the command line with javac, not from the IDE (DrJava). That way you can compare. Or post the program so we can reproduce.

Comment: @ewramner Oh ok so type run class_name in the command line of Dr Java?

Comment: No, create a text file named YourClass.java and invoke "javac YourClass.java" from a command prompt in your operating system in the folder where you put the java file.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you keep having this problem with DrJava, but I'll post my solution in case someone else has the same issue.

I had exactly the same problem as you mentioned in DrJava. It would continuously show the same error, while invoking a method from *java.util.Arrays*, such as *.toString()*.
I had downloaded the old stable release of DrJava (Windows App) through their website, as well as installing the latest updated JDK version. However, this didn't solve the problem.
I tried installing other IDE, such as Eclipse, and it worked perfectly.

Thanks to a friend of mine who had the same problem, I was able to fix this. It worked for the both of us.

Try installing the latest current stable release drjava-beta-2019-220051:
(https://sourceforge.net/projects/drjava/files/).

And for the JDK, I used the jdk-8u25-windows-x64 (this may vary with your OS and processor type):
(https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html)

I'm not sure if this would be the best solution. But after this, it worked perfectly, as I was able to access all methods. Despite this, I still kept installed the latest JDK, which helped me to keep using Eclipse.

Good luck!